# Can an instance of a type class object inherit a value of instance of a parent given in js?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to make a program that allows you to calculate, how much a person on a students apartment, should pay for a invoice given.

At first I had created a Invoice and a Roomie classes and all worked just fine.
Continuing whit this, I had implemented the Apartment class, that has some property in it but a really important one for the logic of the program, the number of rooms.

The thing that I want to happen, is that you can create a instance of an Apartment (myHouse) and every time you add a Invoice gets the values of it.

```js
class Apartment {
    constructor(id, adress, numberOfRooms) {
        this.id = id;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.numberOfRooms = numberOfRooms;
        this.roomies = [];
        this.invoices = [];
    }
    addRoomie(roomie) {
        this.roomies.push(roomie);
    }
    addInvoice(invoice) {
        this.invoices.push(invoice);
    }
}

class Invoice {
    constructor(total, type, begin, end) {
        //Ask for this!

        this.total = total;
        this.type = type;
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;

        this.payed = false;
        this.totalFractionated = this.totalPerPerson();
        this.debtors = {};
    }
    totalPerPerson() {
            const { begin, end, total, numberOfRooms } = this;
            const difference = end.getTime() - begin.getTime();
            const daysOfInterval = difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            const totalPerDay = total / daysOfInterval;
            return totalPerDay / 5; // This 5 I wanted to be numberOfRooms specify on the Aparment class
        }
```

Of course that I can put the `super` method and everything, but I have to specify the values of the invoice (numberOfRooms) every time this way.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question as you mention: you don't want to call numberOfRooms every time... do you use ```class Invoice extends Apartment``` or just ```super``` ?

Answer (score 0):

So, first thing, you shouldn't use inheritance here cause an Invoice isn't a specialized case of Apartment.

Said that, there are couple ways you can do this:

1. When you create an Invoice you pass the Apartment instance to the constructor so you can save it an refer it later as `this.apartment.numberOfRooms`
2. You can move the `totalPerPerson` method to the Apartment class and call it passing the index of the invoice you want as parameter, since seems like you're saving the invoices there
3. You can make a function that isn't part of any of those 2 classes and have it receive an instance of an Invoice and an instance of an Apartment as parameters

Comment: Hi Syder I really like your answer and appreciate that you take the time to answer it. Considering that I will like this to be index on a HTML, what approach you may take?

Comment: Also, let said that some child object wants to get the values of his parent? How this problem may be address it?

Comment: I like the first approach the most. In that case once you saved the instance of the apartment as a member variable in the invoice you can just access it as you do for other member variable using this.apartment

Answer (score 0):

From experience, you might be missing some critical objects. Roomies have no relationship with an apartment whatsoever. You might be missing the Tenant class. Tenants occupy a room. Each tenant has a room instance, so you are also missing the room class. We can also make a room extend an apartment so that it can get its properties of the apartment which includes an address e.t.c. Each tenant in a room can have an invoice property if the monthly invoice will be splitted or each room can have an invoice property if the tenants decided together how to pay the rent every month. This will enable us have the following. Since pure JS does not have an abstract class, we will make an apartment a normal class.

```
class Apartment {
    this.address = "1234 HackerWay, linux ln, 000000";
    this.numberOfRooms = 20;
}

class Room extends Apartment {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.isOccupied = false;
        this.tenants = [];
        this.maximumTenantsAllowed = 2;
        this._invoice = new Invoice();
    }

    addTenant(tenant) {
        if(this.isFull) throw "Room at maximum capacity";
        this.tenants.push(tenant);
    }

    get isFull() {
        return this.tenants.length === this.maximumTenantsAllowed;
    }

    /// Returns the invoice object
    get invoice() {
        return this._invoice;
    }

    get numberOfTenants() {
        return this.tenants.length;
    }
}

class Tenant {
    constructor(tenantName) {
        this.name = tenantName;
        this._invoice = new Invoice();
    }

    get Invoice() {
        return this._invoice;
    }
}

class Invoice {

    generateInvoice(invoiceObject) {
        if(invoiceObject instanceof Room) // write logic for Room
        if(invoiceObject instanceof Tenant) // write logic for tenant
    }
}
```

If there is a logic need to know if the apartment is full, create a RealEstateAgent class that keeps track of the apartment and modify the Room code as needed.

I didn't test the code. I only presented you a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had earlier provided a OOP based answer that you can build on but it has limitations. Below is an algorithmic approach. This is just a framework that you can build on.

```
class Apartment {
  constructor(name = "Apartment",address = "1234 HackerWay, linux ln, 000000") {
    this.address = address;
    this.name = name;

    // This can also be a doubly linked list but for the sake of
    // learning, we just use an array. A doubly linkedlist will allow
    // us know which room is next to which within O(1) complexity.
    // Keeping it in an array will cause at least O(n)
    this.rooms = [
      new Room(1),
      new Room(2),
      new Room(3),
      new Room(4),
      new Room(5),
    ];
  }

  // returns the first available room that is not filled
  // to maximum capacity
  get firstAvailableVacancy() {
    return this.rooms.find((e) => !e.isFull);
  }

  // returns first empty room
  get firstEmpty() {
    return this.rooms.find((e) => e.isVacant);
  }

  findRoomByNumber(number) {
    return this.rooms.find((e) => e.id === number);
  }

  get numberOfRooms() {
    return this.rooms.length;
  }

  get hasVacancy() {
    return Boolean(this.firstAvailableVacancy) || Boolean(this.firstEmpty);
  }

  get hasEmptyRoom() {
    return Boolean(this.firstEmpty);
  }

  /// Or whatever algorithm for calculating cost
  generateCostOfRoom(room) {
    // algorithm to generate cost of room
  }

  // Adds tenant to room based on if they wish to have a
  // co-tenant or not
  addTenant(tenant) {
    if (!this.hasVacancy) throw "No vacancy, check back again";
    if (tenant.acceptsCoTenant) {
      let vacantRoom = this.firstAvailableVacancy;
      if (vacantRoom.hasTenant && vacantRoom.tenants[0].acceptsCoTenant) {
        vacantRoom.addTenant(tenant);
        this.generateCostOfRoom(vacantRoom);
        tenant.room = vacantRoom;
        return vacantRoom;
      }
    } else {
      let vacantRoom = this.firstEmpty;
      if (!vacantRoom)
        throw "No vacancy, check back again or consider haviing a co-tenant";
      vacantRoom.addTenant(tenant);
      this.generateCostOfRoom(vacantRoom);
      tenant.room = vacantRoom;
      return vacantRoom;
    }
  }
}

class Room {
  constructor(roomNumber) {
    this.id = roomNumber;
    this.tenants = [];
    this.maximumTenantsAllowed = 2;
    this._invoice = new Invoice();
    this.cost = 0;
  }

  addTenant(tenant) {
    if (this.isFull) throw "Room at maximum capacity";
    this.tenants.push(tenant);
  }

  get isVacant() {
    return this.tenants.length == 0;
  }

  get hasTenant() {
    return this.tenants.length > 0;
  }

  get isFull() {
    return this.tenants.length === this.maximumTenantsAllowed;
  }

  /// Returns the invoice object
  get invoice() {
    return this._invoice;
  }

  get numberOfTenants() {
    return this.tenants.length;
  }
}

class Tenant {
  constructor(tenantName, acceptsCoTenant) {
    this.name = tenantName;
    this.acceptsCoTenant = acceptsCoTenant;
    this.room = null;
    this._invoice = new Invoice();
  }

  get Invoice() {
    return this._invoice;
  }
}

class Invoice {
  generate(entity) {
    if (entity instanceof Room) {
      // Write logic. You can share the cost between tenants
    }
    if (entity instanceof Tenant) {
      // Write logic. Divide tenant room cost by number of tenants in the room
    }
  }
}

let apartment = new Apartment();
apartment.addTenant(new Tenant("Michael", false));
apartment.addTenant(new Tenant("Joe", false));
apartment.addTenant(new Tenant("Mary", true));
apartment.addTenant(new Tenant("Turtle", true));

let room2 = apartment.findRoomByNumber(2);
console.log(room2.tenants);
if(room2.hasTenant) {
    let tenant1 = room2.tenants[0];
  console.log(tenant1.Invoice);
}
```